# Outlook 365 gives an error Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again. when trying to send an email automatically

Tags: outlook, office365

I have an accounting application that i use to send emails. Recently with the latest Outlook 365 update, every time i try and send an email, i get the error
"Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again."

The application is working through OLE to communicate with Outlook.  In the application, there is an option to show the email before sending. This requires myself to click on Send.  This option works fine.
However if do not want to see the email before sending and want it to be sent automatically, this is when the error comes up.

I have changed the Programmatic Access to to never warn me and allow 3rd party applications to go through. Prior to changing this setting, outlook use to pop up with a box asking permission for the application to go through. I used to click Allow and the error still appeared. With the above change, it does not prompt for me to allow but the error still appears.

Comment: seems to be same question as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65196594/106567