# Sending emails programmatically from the custom application stopped working with latest Outlook 365 update

Tags: .net, email, outlook, com, office365

Since the last Outlook 365 update, the sending of email programmatically from the a .NET application stopped working with error stating "Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again".

However, the saving of the mail (to the draft folder) and getting the email being displayed in a new mail (Outlook) dialog, still works.

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise (Version 20H2 Build 19042.662) and Outlook 365 (Version 2011 Build 13426.20308).

Can anyone please explain why Outlook 365 Send method behaves different as compared to the previous Outlook versions.

Here is an excerpt from the code. The full sample project can be downloaded [here](https://dominogrupa-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/hrvoje_dominogrupa_hr/ESVoHP81NDBDtCf9Aulra3QBOG6N-iqFsjuUtn8fnaWvqw?e=lLBuag).

```
internal void Send(string to, string subject, string message, OutlookActionType actionType)
        {
            _mail = _app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
            _namespace.Logon(null, null, true);

            _mail.To = to;
            _mail.Subject = subject;
            _mail.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

            if (actionType == OutlookActionType.Send)
            {
                _mail.SaveSentMessageFolder = _namespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
                _inspector = _mail.GetInspector; // This ensures signature to be added to the body of the message
                _mail.HTMLBody = message + _mail.HTMLBody;
                _mail.Send(); // this raises the exception stating "Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again."
            }
            else if (actionType == OutlookActionType.Display)
            {
                _mail.SaveSentMessageFolder = _namespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
                _inspector = _mail.GetInspector; // This ensures signature to be added to the body of the message
                _mail.HTMLBody = message + _mail.HTMLBody;
                _mail.Display(); // this works
            }
            else
            {
                _mail.SaveSentMessageFolder = _namespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts);
                _inspector = _mail.GetInspector; // This ensures signature to be added to the body of the message
                _mail.HTMLBody = message + _mail.HTMLBody;
                _mail.Save(); // this works
            }
        }
```

If `_mail.GetInspector` line is removed, then it works, but without that line, the signature doesn't get added to the message, so that is not an option.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
_inspector.Close(olSave);
```

just before

```
_mail.Send();
```

It seems that Outlook 365 raise an error if you try to send a mail and the Inspector is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

`GetInspector` no longer adds the signature. Only `MailItem.Display` does.

See [Inserting Signature into Outlook email from Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233264/inserting-signature-into-outlook-email-from-excel-vba)